# Comparison Tropical Storm Wind Speed

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I am investigating wind speed of tropical storms between 2 years. There are an unequal number of storms per year, however want to test if the wind speeds are significantly similar or different. I checked the use of a t-test or ANOVA, however am a little confused how to statistically compare this data.

Comment: What is measured? Maxim Windows speedometer? Mean? Er need moredetails . Nice og You Aldo van show a plot

Answer (score 1):

An independent sample t test does not require equal sample sizes.

If you want to compare the mean wind speed, you can use a t-test, provided it meets the other assumptions.